# Export mysql (sequelize) table data to json by nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, json, node.js

I am having json data, i want to export that as data.xlsx. For example

I have table there is a **export** button, if user click that export button, this ng-click function will work.

controllers.js:

```
$scope.exportDataXlsx = function () {
        var json = $scope.contacts;
        console.log(json);
        $http.post('/api/exportcontactsxlsx', json).then(function (response) {
            $state.reload();
            toastr.success("exported successfully!");
        });
    };
```

My api code:

```
exports.exportContactsXlsx = function (req, res) {
    var data = req.body;
    var xls = json2xls(data);
    fs.writeFileSync('data.xlsx', xls, 'binary');
}
```

I am using npm package called jsonexport.

If i click export, the file will downloaded to my project.

But i need output, when user click export button The 'data.xlsx' file should be downloaded in chrome left corner, and in user default download directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after saving your file in your server. what you need is to send the name of your file so you can access it from the browser :

```
$scope.exportDataXlsx = function () {
    var json = $scope.contacts;
    console.log(json);
    $http.post('/api/exportcontactsxlsx', json).then(function (response) {
        downloadFile(response.fileName) // make sure response.fileName has the file name
        $state.reload();
        toastr.success("exported successfully!");
    });
};
function downloadFile(name) {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.download = name;
    link.href = '/files/' + name;
    link.click();
}
```

server :

```
// in app.js, to serve your files as static files
app.use("/files", express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'files')));

// send the the name of your file to the client
exports.exportContactsXlsx = function (req, res) {
    var data = req.body;
    var xls = json2xls(data);
    fs.writeFileSync(path.join(__dirname,'../files/data.xlsx'), xls, 'binary');
    //changed the directory
    res.json({ fileName: 'data.xlsx' });
}
```

Comment: data.xslx is downloaded, but when i opened it is showing UI page, not table data.

Comment: @MohamedSameer make sure that the file is saved in `files` directory

Comment: In file directory i have data.xlsx if i opened this, table data looks fine, but the file downloaded in chrome, when i opened its not displaying table data

Comment: @MohamedSameer  is the `files` direcotry in the same level as `node_modules`?

Comment: No inside routes directory i have **files**  directory

Comment: @MohamedSameer this is the problem, see the update : `fs.writeFileSync(path.join(__dirname,'../','files/data.xlsx')`

Comment: @MohamedSameer the directory **files** must be in the root of the project

Comment: If i need CSV? can i use this same functionality?

Comment: @MohamedSameer there's json2csv module you can use it the same way :) https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2csv

Answer (score 1):

You have to set parametrs in the res headers.

You can try for the following:

```
var fields = ['firstName', 'email'];
                var csv = json2csv({ data: resp, fields: fields });
                res.set('Cache-Control', 'max-age=0, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate');
                res.set('Content-Type','application/force-download');
                res.set('Content-Type','application/octet-stream');
                res.set('Content-Type','application/download');
                res.set('Content-Disposition','attachment;filename=userList.csv');
                res.set('Content-Transfer-Encoding','binary');
                res.send(csv);
```

SO when you hit the API in browser, it will ask for SaveFile option and if user clicks OK it will be downloaded to default Download directory of chrome.

Comment: Can you be specific? is incoming file coming as xlsx format? i cant understand your code.